# Python: Split a string, including the whitespace character

Tags: string, python-2.7, split

I'm trying to split a given string into its component characters, while keeping the `whitespace characters` in place. An example of what this should look like is:

```
input: 'the string'

output: ['t', 'h', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

I am relatively new to python (using 2.7.6) and I am aware of the `.split()` method. I know it assumes splitting on the whitespace character `(' ')` if the delimiter is not set. However, when I specify that the delimiter is empty (ie split all characters) with `string.split('')`, it returns `ValueError: empty separator.`

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to split a string, while keeping whitespace characters? I understand that this could be accomplished with a for loop going over every character in the string and appending it to a list, but I'm hoping to find a way without doing so.

This is also my first post on stackoverflow, so hopefully this is understandable and has not already been answered. Thanks.

Comment: Note: Most things you'd use the list for, you could just use the string directly. Iterating over it or indexing it both work the same for the string or the list, as do any functions that work by iterating over or indexing their inputs. Consider whether you actually need this list.

Comment: The only reason (I thought) I needed a list was that I wanted to be able to change an individual element of the list, and since strings are immutable, I figured I'd have to utilize a list. Turns out you were right, just had to concatenate the character with the two halves of the string. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cast `list()` to the string:

```
>>> list('the string')
['t', 'h', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Comment: Very succinct, simple explanation. Of course! Makes total sense. Thanks!